# Solution folder is not created on disk after adding it using Visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have created new solution folder under the root of the solution but when I go to the solution folder on disk it's not found there and when right click on that solution folder there is no  **Open Folder in File Explorer** option.

Could you please help me to solve this issue?

**P.S:**

I am using community edition